# How-to handle errors in Vim Script?

Tags: vim, folding

In my `.vimrc` file, I have the following function, which folds the licensing information on the top of some `.hpp` and `.cpp` files:

```
" Skip license 
function! FoldLicense()
    if !exists("b:foldedLicense")
        let b:foldedLicense = 1
        1;/\*\//fold
    endif
endfunction

au BufRead *.hpp call FoldLicense()
au BufRead *.cpp call FoldLicense()
```

This works well, but if I open a `.cpp` file which **doesn't** have any licensing information block, Vim complains that the pattern is *not found*. Fair enough, but is there a way so that he stops complaining and just *does nothing* if the pattern is not found ?

Thanks !

#### Edit: complete solution (using Bryan Ross answer)

```
" Skip license 
function! FoldLicense()
    if !exists("b:foldedLicense")
        let b:foldedLicense = 1
        silent! 1;/\*\//fold
    endif
endfunction

au BufRead *.hpp call FoldLicense()
au BufRead *.cpp call FoldLicense()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this might work:

```
silent! 1;/\*\//fold
```

Comment: I had a try without the `!` which didn't worked... Adding it solves everything. Many thanks !